# Android airplane mode example

Tags: android

I used this piece of code to turn on and off airplane mode of a Android 4.1.2 device:

```
boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
                     getContentResolver(),
                     Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;

             Settings.System.putInt(
                     getContentResolver(),
                     Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
             intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
             sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The code runs fine, but in order to fully understand why it works I have some questions.

1. Why this code doesn't work if I comment:

   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
                    intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
2. Do I have to always to broadcast an intent after I make any changes in the settings?

Could someone please explain it in more details?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I'm guessing just setting a system variable doesn't actually do anything. You have to broadcast the intent to let the system know that it actually has been changed so that it then can do what needs to be done, such as turning off the radios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings.System.putInt()` actually changes the `int` value, but the system does not notifies it. It does not read this setting in a loop...

So, to make the system aware of that change, you send a broadcast that the system listen to, will then parse its content, notice the setting change and do stuff accordingly.

*So you can't have this code to work without sending the broadcast, because that's what notifies the system about the change you just made. And yes you have to use that broadcast to notice it.*